# Facebook post to fan page using php sdk5 graph api 2.4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a automatic post script to fanpage using php SDK v5 and Graph API 2.4 !

I created two scripts:

1 - To get the list of page access tokens using publish_actions and manage_pages permissions. (returning ok)

2 - Offline publish to fanpage. (fail)

1) The first script works fine:

```
<?php
session_start(); 

require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0-dev/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

// config APP_ID e SECRET
define('APP_ID', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('APP_SECRET', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

// instancia
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'     => APP_ID,
    'app_secret' => APP_SECRET,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4'
]);

if(isset($_SESSION['fb_access_token'])) {
    $accessToken = $_SESSION['fb_access_token'];

} else {

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

        if(isset($accessToken)) {
            $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

            // longlived access token
            if (!$accessToken->isLongLived()) {
                $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken); 
            }
        }

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
}

if(isset($accessToken)) {
    // Logged in!
    $_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

    try {
        $response = $fb->get('/me/accounts', $accessToken);

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($response->getDecodedBody());
        echo '</pre>';

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } 
} else {
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    $redirect_url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirect_url, [ 'manage_pages', 'publish_actions' ]);
    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
}
```

2) The second script fails: (the script should work even if I am disconnected from facebook):

```
<?php
session_start(); 

// autoloader 
require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0-dev/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

define('APP_ID', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('APP_SECRET', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$page_access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

// instance
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'     => APP_ID,
    'app_secret' => APP_SECRET,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
]);

$linkData = [
  'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
  'message' => 'User provided message',
];

try {
    $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, $page_access_token);

} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

I`m getting the error:

> Graph returned an error: Error validating access token: Session does not match current stored session. This may be because the user changed the password since the time the session was created or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons.

In old graph api versions with php sdk v3, it works in a similar way...

What's wrong ?

Comment: you are aware that you need publish_pages to post as page, right?

Comment: that is, it is working now. I forgot publish_pages ! Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i suggested in the comments, you need `publish_pages` to [post as Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/feed#publish). After authorizing with `publish_pages`, you can get a Page Token with `/me/accounts` and use the resulting Token to post as Page.

Make sure you are using an Extended Page Token if you want to store it. It is valid forever.

More information about Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Actually, I don't get the idea what you guys are talking about. I searched the links but didn't get any word such as 'publish_pages'. Can you give a kick-start?

Comment: i´ve added a link ("post as Page") to the api reference. everything you need to know about posting to a page is in there.

Comment: Thanks for that. Giving publish_pages permission helped me out.

Comment: I also dont unsderstand you guy talking about `publish_pages` how can I do it?

Comment: please read the facebook docs about that, there is plenty of information about the login process, including example code for different languages.